# extract date from object id and export it to csv in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoexport

I am pretty new to mongodb. Am trying to export data from a collection to a csv file. I have done that and it works fine. I have a question . Is there a way to export just date from ObjectId to a new column. I understand we can get date from ObjectId using ObjectId.getTimestamp(). Is there a way we can do the same for mongoexport. Below is the query i use to export data

```
mongoexport --db MyDB --collection CollectionName --type=csv --fieldFile fieldsList.txt --out Data.csv
```

Comment: Not with `mongoexport`. There are other ways though, such as what you mention. The best `mongoexport` can to is "query". Not manipulate.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with `mongoexport`, but if the case is generally simple enough then you can really just use the mongo shell.

For instance to just export data from all fields in a collection with a flat structure and append the last field as the timestamp then you can do:

```
mongo localhost/MyDB --quiet --eval 'db.CollectioName.find().forEach(d => print(Object.keys(d).concat(["@time"]).map(k => (k === "@time") ? d["_id"].getTimestamp().valueOf() : d[k].valueOf() ).join(", ")))' > Data.csv
```

Showing the script part as pretty:

```
db.CollectioName.find().forEach(d =>
  print(Object.keys(d).concat(["@time"]).map(k => 
    (k === "@time") ? d["_id"].getTimestamp().valueOf() : d[k].valueOf() ).join(", ")
  )
)
```

Which essentially says that when iterating all documents for the given collection we

- Grab a list of all document fields
- Append the "special" field of `@time` to the end of the list
- Loop those fields and return an array of values - where the `@time` gets the timestamp from the `ObjectId` in `_id`
- Join the result array with commas and print all of it out

If you had a list of fields then you could simply replace the `Object.keys(d)` part with an array of field names, such as:

```
db.CollectioName.find().forEach(d =>
  print(["_id","field1","field2"].concat(["@time"]).map(k => 
    (k === "@time") ? d["_id"].getTimestamp().valueOf() : d[k].valueOf() ).join(", ")
  )
)
```

But really as long as you provide the database to connect to and the [`--quiet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-quiet) and [`--eval`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-eval) options with the script line, then you can simply redirect the output to your destination file, from any scripting you want.

It does not take **all** considerations for a CSV into account. But it is a *"quick and dirty"* solution for most basic cases at a pinch, or at the very least a starting point for expansion without writing a full program listing.

If you really want more than this, then there are drivers for your language of choice as well as a plethora of CSV writing libraries for every single one of those languages. And it's really not that much harder than the listing here, especially with a library taking all "quoting" considerations into mind.

Comment: thanks for writing a detailed answer. i ll try this out . thanks again